# How to make new array with old array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, vue.js

I'm trying to clean a this array:

```
 [
    {
      "Cpf": null,
      "Nascimento": null,
      "Sexo": null,
      "OnlyPerson": false,
      "IsFinanc": false,
      "Senha": null,
      "ConfirmaSenha": null,
      "Remover": false,
      "TipoStr": null,
      "FiltroStr": null,
      "IdAgenciaLogarComo": 0,
      "DontHashPass": false,
      "IsPessoaSimples": false,
      "IsVisitante": false,
      "Permited": false,
      "Id": 21980,
      "Nome": "arrozfeijao",
      "Ativo": true,
      "Criacao": "2021-08-19T14:09:06.173",
      "UltimaAlteracao": null,
      "Email": "arrozfeijao@gmail.com",
      "IdAgencia": 1,
      "IdEndereco": null,
      "IdPermissao": 4,
      "Observacoes": null,
      "Endereco": {
        "Id": 0,
        "Cep": null,
        "Logradouro": null,
        "Numero": null,
        "Complemento": null,
        "Bairro": null,
        "Estado": null,
        "Cidade": null
      },
      "Parceiro": null,
      "Contato": [],
      "Permissao": {
        "Id": 4,
        "Descricao": "Cliente",
        "Pessoa": []
      },
      "AlterarSenha": [],
      "Rede": [],
      "Provider": [],
      "AlertaPreco": [],
      "Pedido2": [],
      "_PageNumber": 0,
      "PageNumber": 0,
      "PageSize": 0,
      "OrderBy": null,
      "OrderDesc": false
    }
  ]
```

This array is a checkbox selected in a table ->
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAdXY.png)
I need a function to clean array fo every time I select one more checkbox.
I has tryied to *push* all I need to new a variable, but if a select other checkbox (with other informations) dont work...

I need export to CSV this informations, but I don't need all this, I just wanna:

- "Cpf"
- "Nascimento"
- "Sexo"
- "Id"
- "Nome"
- "Ativo"
- "Criacao"
- "UltimaAlteracao"
- "Email"
- "Observacoes"
- "Endereco".

I know a i need a *for*, i just do no how to make this function :c

Comment: How many objects will there be in the array?

Comment: Also: no you don't. JS offers quite a few methods to work with array data, including [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) which is almost certainly more appropriate in this case (unless you're optimizing already working code, which is pretty clearly not the case here yet).

Comment: Unmitigated, if select all? i do ha no idea haha a lot


 Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans, how i can make this function using Array.filter in my case?
suposing my variable is **multipleSelection.data** and contain this array up us

Comment: @Veterano I posted an answer which handles multiple objects in your array. Please comment, if this solves your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it looks like your data belongs to one person and there could be multiple persons, here is a solution:

Declare your arrays:

```
data: function () {
  return {
    oldArray: [],
    includesArray: ["Cpf", "Nascimento", "Sexo", "Id", "Nome", "Ativo", "Criacao", "UltimaAlteracao", "Email", "Observacoes", "Endereco"],
    newArray: []
  }
}
```

`oldArray` would the the data from your question, `includesArray` are the keys you want to transfer to the new array and `newArray` will have this data.

Add this to you component:

```
created() {
    for (const [key] of Object.entries(this.oldArray)) {
      let tempObject = {};
      for (const [keys, values] of Object.entries(this.oldArray[key])) {
        if (this.includesArray.includes(keys)) {
          tempObject[keys] = values;
        }
      }
      this.newArray[key] = tempObject;
    }
  }
```

Comment: The problem now is clean array, case user Unselect a checkbox, I gonna make work thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can use Lodash pick method to pick the properties from object and you can map it and the pseudo-code is

```
let newArray = oldArray.map(item => {
return _.pick(item, ['id', 'name']);
});
```